# Priority checker for infix-to-postfix converter

Tags: c

I am trying to implement an infix to postfix conversion program using stacks.  I have actually have done it successfully, but I'm uncertain about the complexity of the logic that I used for the priority checking.

```
int hasLowerPriority(char ch,char ch2)
{
    int num=0,num2=0;
    if(ch=='+'||ch=='-')
        num=1;
    if(ch=='*'||ch=='/')
        num=2;
    if(ch2=='+'||ch2=='-')
        num2=1;
    if(ch2=='*'||ch2=='/')
        num2=2;
    if(num<num2)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

To keep it simple I am using four basic operators only. I am looking for optimized code for the same operation. Can I reduce its complexity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is duplicated code that can be removed.

```
static int precedence(char operator) {
    switch (operator) {
      case '*': case '/':
        return 2;
      case '+': case '-':
        return 1;
      default:
        return 0;
    }
}

int hasLowerPriority(char operator, char otherOperator) {
    return precedence(operator) < precedence(otherOperator);
}
```

At that point, you might as well get rid of the `hasLowerPriority()` function altogether, since `precedence(operator) < precedence(otherOperator)` is clearer and more readable.

(Note that `operator` is a reserved keyword in C++, but not in C.  You might want to rename it to `op` or something.)

Comment: Thanks I was also thinking about this redundancy. But I forget the great switch statement :)